# How to get update all hidden fields with same name?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have multiple hidden field with same name on html page like below

```
    <input type="hidden" name="customerID" value="aa190809" />
```

I need to update values of all hidden field with same name i.e. `customerID`

I know how to do it(through Jquery) if html page contains single hidden field with `customerID` like below  but not sure if there are multiple hidden field with same name

```
            if(updatedCsrf !== null) {
                var customerIDHidden = $("input[name='customerID']");
                if(customerIDHidden !== null) {
                    customerID.val("some_value");
                }
            }
```

Comment: Where is `customerID` coming from? is that actually supposed to be `customerIDHidden`?

Comment: why do you want to use multiple hidden fields with same name...? at the end you will always get single value so whats the use...?

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti you are right. Its existing application where these fields are generated dynamically. Constraint is i won't be able to refactor it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something like this:

```
$("input[name=customerID]").each(function(){
    this.value ="new value"
})
```

`this` will reference each DOM element. You can parse it again to jQuery DOM element by replacing `this.value` to `$(this).val("new value")` but since you only need to change the value its better with javascript vanilla

Comment: what if `input[name=customerID]` is null or does not exists ? won't `$("input[name=customerID]").each(function()` break ?

Comment: no, if there are no elements jquery will return an empty array, so it wont do anything

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with pure `JS`,

```
var x = document.getElementsByName("customerID");
for(var i=0; i < x.length;i++){
  x[i].value='new value';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery each function

```
$("input[name='customerID']").each(function(){
    $(this).val("some-value");
});
```